# AWS Cloudwatch Alarm Passing Parameters to another Parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm pretty new to creating Alarms on AWS Cloudwatch so i'm not sure if this is possible but I was able to create an  alarm and everything works so far but I want to parameterize the hard coded variable in another parameter which is the expression for which our alarm would alert off of. As it currently stands the code looks like this.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Parameters:
    AlarmExpression:
        Type: String
        Default: IF( m1 > .9 || m2 > .9 || m3 > .9 || m4 > .9 || m5 > .9 || m6 > .9
                      || m7 > .9 || m8 > .9 || m9 > .9 || m10 > .9,1,0 )
```

This is what I've tried but it would never pass the parameter threshold into the other parameter.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Parameters:
    Threshold:
        Type: Number
        Default: .9
    AlarmExpression:
        Type: String
        Default: IF( m1 > !Ref Threshold || m2 > !Ref Threshold || m3 > !Ref Threshold ||    
                     m4 > !Ref Threshold || m5 > !Ref Threshold || m6 > !Ref Threshold ||    
                     m7 > !Ref Threshold || m8 > !Ref Threshold || m9 > !Ref Threshold ||   
                     m10 > !Ref Threshold,1,0 )
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do this?

Answer (score 0):

Its **not possible**, as `Paramters` can't reference other parameters. They can only be [references in](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#parameters-section-structure-requirements):

> You can reference parameters from the Resources and Outputs sections of the template.

You would need develop a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) or [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) to do what you want.